# Why does an OS need a Blocked queue for task scheduling?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

Why does an OS need a Blocked queue for task scheduling?

Since each semaphore has a queue of tasks blocked by it, whenever the semaphore is released (1 time) a task from its queue could be directly added back to the Ready queue of the OS.

**Situation:** 
*3 Tasks* (**T1**, **T2**, **T3**) all use a semaphore **S** accessing some shared data.

1. *Ready Queue*: { **T1**, **T2**, **T3** }, **S** = 1, {}. 
   OS runs **T1**. **T1** takes 1 from **S**.
2. *Ready Queue*: { **T2**, **T3**, **T1** }, **S** = 0, {}. 
   OS runs **T2**. **T2** takes 1 from **S**, and is blocked.
3. *Ready Queue*: { **T3**, **T1** }, **S** = -1, { **T2** }. 
   OS runs **T3**. **T3** takes 1 from **S**, and is blocked.
4. *Ready Queue*: { **T1** }, **S** = -2, { **T2**, **T3** }. 
   OS runs **T1**. **T1** releases 1 to **S** after using shared resource. 
   On release to **S**, OS adds back **T2** to the *Ready Queue*.
5. *Ready Queue*: { **T2**, **T1** }, **S** = -1, { **T3** }. 
   OS runs **T2**. **T2** releases 1 to **S** after using shared resource. 
   On release to **S**, OS adds back **T3** to the *Ready Queue*.
6. *Ready Queue*: { **T3**, **T2**, **T1** }, **S** = 0, {}. 
   OS runs **T3**. **T3** releases 1 to **S** after using shared resource.
7. *Ready Queue*: { **T3**, **T2**, **T1** }, **S** = 1, {}.

The above situation did make use of a blocked queue of **S**, but it did not make use of any global *Blocked Queue*, like the global *Ready Queue* of the OS.

Then, why does the OS maintain / need a *Blocked queue*?

(or, is the blocked queue referred to in OS,  is actually the blocked queue of each semaphore, and there is no global blocked queue?)

Answer (score 0):

Well if I'm understanding the question correctly.

The easiest form of a queue is one built on a linked list. If it's not blocking, it's possible have race conditions. For example, let's say we have Process A and B. Both of them call fork.

A is running and forks.

A prepares to add to the list, size of list is 2. (Example sake)

Context switch to B.

B also forks.

B prepares to add to list, because queue is not blocking, size of list is also 2.

B finishes.

Context switch to A.

A finishes.

The queue will have (in no particular order ) { A , B , A-child }

but B-child will be lost because A-child overwrote it.

To ensure that only one task can be added and removed from the list at the same time, it needs to be mutually exclusive, thus we need the semaphore to block.

But if you think about it, a semaphore is already a blocking queue because in the backend, it does exactly what we need.

The back end of a semaphore is basically 'something that ensures no interrupts can occur' (the lowest level form of blocking there is) during a task, and anything else calling the semaphore will be added to a queue in the semaphore.

So yes, a blocking queue is needed for an OS.

Comment: Is the list, Process A and B are adding to, a shared data list, and is the queue mentioned later the running queue?

Comment: The running queue is simply some queue that has to be mutually exclusive when threads access it for reasons stated above. The shared data list protected by a semaphore is operationally equivalent to a single semaphore. Sorry if I'm confusing you more.